# Display Personal Billing Information Using Google Search

Tags: google-search

Hi I saw some mobile carriers display personal billing amount of the particular customer on the customer google search. As a example once I want to get to know about my current mobile phone balance, I should type what is my ABC Carrier balance. Then google search display exact amount of the balance.

My problem is how to do such integration on google search? Are there having any API support to do it?

ABC Carrier is the example name